# One login on multiple subdomain laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to create one login for my two laravel application, one on subdomain `portal.mydomain.com` and the other is `app.mydomain.com` (if not logged in, will redirect to `portal.mydomain.com`).

In this case, I try to use database driver, so I create table session with laravelish style.

When I login via `portal.mydomain.com`, I see session data on table session is updated like this :

```
|id|user_id|ip_address|user_agent|payload|last activity
|ec4156b47e3e527af871c7b4b688393aee631cda|9|(myipaddress)|(myuser_agent)|YTozOntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiWnQ1OXpBNzhsZ3I4ZVJUc2tXeEtiTExkU1R6T1hHSUNBYWxrSU1obCI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MzQ6Imh0dHA6Ly95ZHBidWRnZXQudGFuZ2tvdGEuY29tL3Rlc3QiO31zOjY6Il9mbGFzaCI7YToyOntzOjM6Im9sZCI7YTowOnt9czozOiJuZXciO2E6MDp7fX19|1503693006
```

And on portal application, it successful to login. But when I try to access app application, it updated column `user_id` set to `NULL` and the payload change and its force logout on portal application too.

Idk why its updated the value on session table when its should be put the value

Comment: What's your [session cookie domain](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L142) setting? If I'm not mistaken, if you'd set the domain in both projects to `.mydomain.com` - they would share the session, so login and logout would be reflected on the sister platform.

Comment: i already set domain on session setting

Comment: The problem is, when i access app.mydomain.com , its override session to be null , so it's always force logout to both subdomain

Comment: Oh its solved, its my mistake on configure session file, i set encryption true for portal but i set encryption false in app , so it will never match a session before